# Facebook Like Chat Messenger/phonegap and its requirements

Tags: ajax, cordova

Please I need venerable expert contribution on this only:

1.) Am trying to get insight on how to build a Facebook like chat Messenger using Ajax,Jquery,html5 and Phonegap as a Wrapper(For cross multiple platform). Is this a good idea or
approach?

2.) For Chat application I want to use either Ejabbered Client with XMPP or Web sockets. The chat will be require to
periodically display typing status, instant notifications, Messaging sounds etc

Between this two technology Websocket and
Ejabbered/XMPP which one is the best in terms of performance, latency reduction,cpu and Bandwith consumption reduction and battery life
saver etc. Again between the Ejabbered Client/XMPP and Web Socket which of them is supported by phonegap.

3.) Does every hosting company supports Web sockets and Ejabbered Client/XMPP Server

4.) Please emphasize on the reason why one is prefered to the other.

Thanks

Comment: I've built applications tied to cloud storage using jQuery / AJAX, HTML, and PhoneGap.  I used Framework7 for an iOS native feel, that I customized to meet my desired look and feel (CSS).  I found that jQuery / AJAX worked quickly and effectively for my application but it's use was not as demanding as a chatting application being simultaneously used by many many people.  I have no experience with Ejabbered Client or Web Sockets so I can't share any of that.  I can say however, that PhoneGap can make some pretty impressive applications.

Comment: Thanks @Philips126 for your response but am still concern about Ejabbered Client/Websocket can someone help

Answer (score 1):

I just did an IM application using Jabber (XMPP) in native android, (not in phonegap); and it works like a charm.

1. Is it a good idea? - well, if you are good and quick at phonegap, then go for it.
2. For a comparison, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560860/2533213) post might help you. I know XMPP better, it is a well-done IM protocol with lots of awesome extensions. Furthermore, this sample [XMPP app on Phonegap](https://github.com/QuickBlox/sample-chat-xmpp-phonegap) might also give you good insight, if not anything more.
3. Many choices. Rent a cloud server. Begin with a [free version Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) server.
   For my Jabber IM app, I installed the opensource [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) IM server quite easily on an Amazon EC2 Server where I quite simply run a Linux machine. [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html) is a step-by-step tutorial on how to install and run a Linux OS up in Amazon with one click!

Comment: what is this Amazon Instance. is it a kind of web hosting companies, what about bandwidth usage. Again am not good at linux so how do i secure the linux machine against attack

Comment: It is like a computer you have at home. You can host any service you want. With one click, you can install the Linux/Windows OS (called instance) on the server. Why don't you use this [free version](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) first?
Bandwidth, you pay based on what you use/ this means as you get more users and more traffic, you can pay more. So there is less waste. You can use free version above, and then search on the web for [comparison price could server](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2014-05-22/cloud-platform-race-salesforce-leads-amazon-microsoft-google).

Comment: What about security issues like hacking the linux server. dont you think that it will require you to hire a linux expert which will cost more money. what also happen if you have a problem that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Security-wise, nothing is 100% secure. You only need to do the right steps. I don't think there is an unresolved issue with this solution. When setting up an server you have [tips and hints](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233) to follow to stay secure. I would recommend, go for it, follow the simple instructions and do not hesitate to ask. 
In case of later on issues, that is why Amazon is one option with its different [support plans](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/).