# Which is best for realtime chat?

Tags: android, sockets, chat, real-time

I'm about to develop mobile app with realtime chat. I am confused about which is best tool for real time chat?

Comment: Both have their own benefits , your answer lies at [this][1] post


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549010/xmpp-vs-websocket

Comment: This question is already closed. So, it should not downvoted again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there have no best choice.
They are used for different usage scenarios.

And, I like "socket".